# ReactAPI using Postman: "Authentication credentials were not provided"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am working with ReactJS and try to get some data from postman. But it gave me the Network error "**Authentication credentials were not provided**"

What's wrong in this code??

```js
import axios from '../axios/axios.js';
import { getAuthenticationToken } from '../utils.js';

export const duplicateAssessment = async (data) => {
    const token = getAuthenticationToken();
    console.log('token',token);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    };
    return axios.get('/assessment/duplicate_assessment/', data, config);
};
```

I want to get the data from the api call.

Comment: _"get some data from postman"_... what exactly do you mean by this? Postman is a client, not a server

Comment: `axios.get()` does not accept a `data` parameter; the 2nd parameter is for `config`. See https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config

Comment: From the axios documentation:

`data` is the data to be sent as the request body
 Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE', and 'PATCH'
 When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
 - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
 - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
 - Node only: Stream, Buffer

Source: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config 

Try excluding the data for the request or if you're building the API yourself, try converting the method to POST if the endpoint really needs to consume data.

Comment: I want to get the data but In the postman I set that as a Post request which casue me this error. Now I fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```js
return axios.get('/assessment/duplicate_assessment/', data, config);
```

to

```js
return axios.get('/assessment/duplicate_assessment/',config);
```

Make sure api url is correct and `axios.get()` method will only take config as second argument. get allow data in query params

```js
return axios.get('/assessment/duplicate_assessment?key=value&key=value',config);
```

If you want to send body need to use the `axios.post()` method.